# NullPointerException in the Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-json

I am getting ***NullPointerException*** in the activity where I am using ***adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();***

Basically in the activity i am parsing the data and I am using the adapter of where the data needs to be setin the ListItems.

**The code of the MainActivity -**

```
public class SearchResultActivityOne extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String url = "http://sikkimexpress.itstunner.com/api/newssearch/a";

    private boolean enableBackNavigation;
    String TAG = "";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private CustomListSearchAdapter adapter;
    public static final String KEY_HEADURL = "news_url";
    public static final String KEY_DETAILS = "news_details";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "news_title";
    String imageURL = "", title = "", description = "";
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        if (enableBackNavigation) {
//            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        }

//        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchResultActivityOne.this);
//        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...Please Wait...");
//        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
//        pDialog.show();

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                hidePDialog();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("HomeNews");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject homenews = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        movie.setNewsId(homenews.getString("NewsId"));
                        movie.setDateTime(homenews.getString("DateTime"));
                        movie.setNewsType(homenews.getString("NewsType"));
                        movie.setTitle(homenews.getString("Title"));
                        movie.setDescription(homenews.getString("Description"));
                        movie.setThumbnailUrl(homenews.getString("MainImageThumbnail"));

                        movieList.add(movie);
                }
            } catch (JSONException exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_about_us:
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchResultActivityOne.this, AboutUs.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_terms_of_use:
                Intent intent_two = new Intent(SearchResultActivityOne.this, TermsUse.class);
                startActivity(intent_two);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_privacy_policy:
                Intent intent_three = new Intent(SearchResultActivityOne.this, PrivacyPolicy.class);
                startActivity(intent_three);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_contact_us:
                Intent intent_four = new Intent(SearchResultActivityOne.this, ContactUs.class);
                startActivity(intent_four);

            case R.id.action_search:

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

**The CustomListViewAdapter**

```
public class CustomListSearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


    public CustomListSearchAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView desciption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desciption);

        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        String text = Html.fromHtml(m.getTitle()).toString();
        title.setText(text);
        String text_two = Html.fromHtml(m.getDescription()).toString();
        desciption.setText(text_two);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your logs with stacktrace please.

Comment: You have to show your error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *adapter* object is not initialized yet so the `notifyDatasetChanged()` will raise a `NullPointerException`.
You'll need something along the lines of

```
adapter = new CustomListSearchAdapter(SearchResultActivityOne.this, movieList);
//Set the adapter to your ListView
```

Before you call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` in your `onCreate()` method.

But I suspect you'll want to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` in the `onResponse()` when your *movieList* actually has items. Also, what is the point of having an adapter without a `ListView`?

I think you are missing some code. Initialize your `ListView` and adapter first. Something like this

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findById(R.id.list);
adapter = new CustomListSearchAdapter(SearchResultActivityOne.this, movieList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You need to add more info to this to make it a complete answer?

Comment: where I have to declare? In my Activity Class?

Comment: Before the `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` call in `onCreate()`. But what is the point of having an adapter without a `ListView`? Did you write this code yourself?

Comment: I am getting empty list. Please help.

Comment: Niels, that wasn't for you

Comment: Well that makes sense because you don't even have a `ListView` in your code.

Comment: Can you please help me in how to implement SearchFilter by implementing my BaseAdapter to Filterable?

Comment: You'll have to create a new question for that and i'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your adapter:

```
adapter = new CustomListSearchAdapter();
```

Then set it on the list view

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Update 1**

In onCreate method:

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
CustomListSearchAdapter adapter = new CustomListSearchAdapter(... arguments ...);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then use this list view to set your adapter

Comment: where I have to declare? In my Activity Class?

Comment: Its working but I can't set the data in the list. When I debugged I m able to enter the response but at the last there is no data in the list result empty list. What should I do?